# having issues with IF clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql

can we add conditions in WHERE clause in MySQL with use of IF construct

e.g.

```
SELECT TABLE1.field2, TABLE2.Field3  FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 using (ID)
WHERE TABLE1.field2 = 'test'
IF (TABLE2.Field3 IS NOT NULL, AND TABLE2.Field3 > 2, '' )
```

Please look at last line carefully.

I want to add `AND TABLE2.Field3 > 2` condition in where clause only if `TABLE2.Field3` after left join is NOT NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will satisfy your condition

```
SELECT TABLE1.field2, TABLE2.Field3  FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 using (ID)
WHERE TABLE1.field2 = 'test'
and (TABLE2.Field3 IS NULL or TABLE2.Field3 > 2 )
```